# Handling rollbacks in a SQL Server catch statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, error-handling

In my reading, I have seen two methods of handling transaction rollbacks in the CATCH section in a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
1: if @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK
2: if XACT_STATE() <> 0 ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Which is better and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [MSDN articl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx)e is a good reference. Quote:

> Both the XACT_STATE and @@TRANCOUNT
>   functions can be used to detect
>   whether the current request has an
>   active user transaction. @@TRANCOUNT
>   cannot be used to determine whether
>   that transaction has been classified
>   as an uncommittable transaction.
>   XACT_STATE cannot be used to determine
>   whether there are nested transactions.

Say you wanted to potentially COMMIT a transaction in some circumstances, then XACT_STATE will help you here as that will identify whether it's possible to commit or not whereas @@TRANCOUNT couldn't tell you that. If you just want to do a ROLLBACK, either would do the job, so it depends on what you actually need.